# Работа с combobox WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, controls

Хочу реализовать следующий режим работы с `ComboBox`. При нажатии на стрелку "вниз", хочу отобразить форму с табличкой для выбора строки.
В связи с этим не могу найти событие, которое отвечает именно за клик на стрелке "вниз" самого `ComboBox`. Dropdown начинает открывать список и отображает пустую строку, даже если нет данных в `ComboBox`, что тоже некрасиво. 
Подскажите вкратце какие события `ComboBox` нужно обработать, чтобы реализовать описанную идею.

Comment: так комбобокс и так работает так как вы описали

Comment: `DropDownStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UzKNTpWUrwzJpqW3niWkV4bml5o2rNIw/view?usp=sharing
Комбик пустой. При клике на стрелку срабатывает событие dropdown. Как не открывать список? Даже если по событию dropdown пропишу form.ShowModal() список все равно откроется и получится отобразится форма и пустой список.